# How to solve error: failed linking file resources

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

The error says that:

> C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\hamm\app\src\main\res\drawable\black_gradient.xml:4:
>   error: '00000000' is incompatible with attribute endColor (attr)
>   color.
>   C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\hamm\app\src\main\res\layout\home_item.xml:8:
>   error: '#e6e6e6' is incompatible with attribute srcCompat (attr)
>   reference [weak]. error: failed linking file resources.

This is the `black_gradient.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#121212"
        android:endColor="00000000" />

</shape>
```

This is my `home_item.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="#e6e6e6" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/btn_news_style"
        android:id="@+id/btn_news"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="News And Highlight"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/black_gradient"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="175dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_img"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/news_img" />

</android.support.constraint.Constrain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it reads:

> error: '00000000' is incompatible with attribute endColor (attr) color.

you need to use hexadecimal notation:

```
android:endColor="#000000"
```

Comment: okay that error sloved, thank you... but there still error here Output:  C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\hamm\app\src\main\res\layout\home_item.xml:8: error: '#e6e6e6e6' is incompatible with attribute srcCompat (attr) reference [weak].
error: failed linking file resources.

Comment: @FarishaSiro the same here: `#e6e6e6e6` should be `#e6e6e6`. there's also a notation with alpha channel... but regular RBG is three times `00` to `FF`, resulting in six digits `0` to `F`.

Comment: ouh i see so i delete the app:srcCompat="#e6e6e6e6" and my app can run without error..thank you so much for your help

Comment: @FarishaSiro `app:srcCompat` should be a `drawable` resource, not a `color` resource.